# JPanel subclass not drawing entire shape

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel subclass and overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and calling `g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 75)`. Inside my main method I initialize it and call `setBounds(50, 400, 500, 75)` on it, but when it draws the rectangle it is only drawing something like this:

```
|________________
```

and missing the two other sides. Sorry I don't have the code, it's on a different computer. Any ideas?

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1):

First, use;

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, 499, 74);
```

Second, don't use `setBounds` make use of appropriate layout managers and override `getPreferredSize` (and if required `getMinimum/MaximumSize`)

Third, don't rely on magic numbers...

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
```

Comment: @Chris I realise that, and unless you have a very good (and I mean VERY GOOD) reason to do so, don't